# Run AJAX script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the ajax, which runs when the user writes something ind `input id=2`

HTML:

```
<input id="2" type="text" onkeyup="posttitulo(this.value)" />
```

SCRIPT:

```
function posttitulo(value){
$.post("getdata/posttitulo.php",{partialStates:value});
}
```

The code works perfectly.. The problem is that I have the javascript function which `onclick` copies value of another input `id=1`, in this case id=2 has the value without typing and `function posttitulo(value)` doesn't work..

So I need Ajax to be executed if:

1) User writes something `onkeyup="posttitulo(this.value)`;

2) the value of id=1 is copied to id=2..

Hope that I explained the problem..
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about <input id="2" type="text" onchange="posttitulo(this.value)" />, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, Already tryed, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `$('#2').keyup();` after you copied a value in the function, which fires `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

create an event listener change() on id=2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#2").change(function(){
  var value=$("#2").val();
  $.post("getdata/posttitulo.php",{partialStates:value});

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with firing the event on the input or recycle the function you already declared. When the button is clicked read the value of the id2 Element and call the posttitulo function with the value as argument.

```
function posttitulo(value){
    console.log('AJAX POST:', value);
}

function buttonClicked() {
    var value = document.getElementById('id2').value;
    posttitulo(value);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/11th3q1o/)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work in your case.

```
<input id="1" type="text" onclick="yourreplacefunction(this.value,2)" />

$(document).on("change keyup", "input", function() {
    $.post("getdata/posttitulo.php",{partialStates:value},function(response){
        //Do with your response
    });
});

function yourreplacefunction(value,toid) {
       $('#'+toid).val(value);
}
```